# Function docstrings not included in generated HTML

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am starting a new Sphinx project to generate documentation from docstrings. I am not able to post my code structure here due to the sensitivity of my project. I have successfully built and generated the HTML with the following commands:

```text
[root@VM_149_39_centos ~/InjectionTool/Injection/docs]# make htmlhelp
Running Sphinx v1.8.6
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [htmlhelp]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [] 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] Injection.facades.stress_facade                                                                                                                                                                                   
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... /root/InjectionTool/Injection/docs/modules.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index                                                                                                                                                                                                              
generating indices... genindex py-modindex
writing additional pages...
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping stopword list...
writing project file...
writing TOC file...
writing index file...
build succeeded, 1 warning.

You can now run HTML Help Workshop with the .htp file in _build/htmlhelp.
```

The HTML was generated but did not contain any docstring defined in the functions. I actually added lots of markup, as seen below. Can anybody help to check why the information was missing from the HTML?

```python
def start_random_stress(self, components=['cpu','memory','filesystem'], stressor_amount=10, exec_order='par', timeout=3600):
     """This method is used to inject the stress on various server components depends on the value of parameter components, refer:
     :py:meth:`stressors.stressor_classes.const` on which components could be used to stress        

     :param components:  list of the os components selected to fault
     :type components: list
     :param stressor_amount: the amount of stressors need to inject for each components
     :type stressor_amount: int
     :param exec_order: execution mode, possible vaule are seq and par
     :type exec_order: str
     :param timeout: Timeout waiting for the recovery of the server
     :type timeout: int
```

Comment: it turns out that the doc appears right after I commented the function level decorator, so why I can not use funciton decorator in this case?

Comment: What function level decorator? The code in the question seems to be a method, not a function btw. Please try to provide a [mcve].